# Find the minimum of $\arccos a+\arcsin a+\arctan a$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, maxima-minima

Find the minimum of

> $$\arccos a+\arcsin a+\arctan a$$

I know that,  the answer is $\frac {\pi}{4}$.

But, I don't know a solution.
Please, explain the solution of problem to me in a very simple way. Because, my mathematics level is too low to compare with you. Can you  explain me the answer in detail, please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What makes you think the answer is $\pi/4?$  Try plotting the graph on Wolfram Alpha

Comment: Is the answer wrong?

Comment: It's right. @saulspatz: This is the graph https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xeipvcwovi  $π/4$  equals $0.78539816339$ which is the minimum value on the graph

Comment: @FreeRadical Okay, I see what you mean.  I just simplified it to $\pi/2 +\tan^{-1}x$ and forgot about the domain.

Comment: Some care is needed in specifying the domain of the expression you want to minimize.  While the domain of $\cos^{-1}$ and of $\sin{-1}$ might be $[-1,+1]$, the natural domain of $\tan^{-1}$ is $(-\infty, +\infty)$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $y = \arccos a+\arcsin a+\arctan a $

$\arccos a+\arcsin a =\frac{\pi}{2}$

So, $y =  \frac{\pi}{2} + \arctan a $

$a$ lies on a subset of $[-1,1]$

Therefore, $y$ will be minimum when $a = -1$

Hence  $y =  \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4}   = 
   \frac{\pi}{4}  $

**Edit: $a$ lies on a subset of $[-1,1]$  because the $\arccos$ or $\arcsin$ function can't take values more than $1$ or less than $-1$**